# How to find and save strings of stuff in a file as variables

Tags: bash, shell, ubuntu

I'd like to know a way, in a bash script to find a string of numbers and save them as a variable

For example, I want to find "Failed" requests in auth.log and find the ip that failed that request, for example like

```
Failed password for invalid user kim from 183.56.129.146 port 49876 ssh2
```

I'd like to record the IP, and the user into variables, like $user1 $ip1 for use later in the script

Since this is the auth.log file, there's gonna be tons of those Failed password statements and stuff, I'd like to save ALL the ips and the user sets for those statements in the whole file, Not as one, but seperately for use in iptables commands later

Is there an easy way of doing this? Please help :)

Answer (score 0):

You should use [fail2ban](http://www.fail2ban.org/wiki/index.php/Main_Page) instead of reinventing the wheel.

If for some odd reasons you can't :

```
declare -A users # declare an array
$(awk '/Failed password/{print "declare users["$6"]="$8}' /var/log/auth.log)
echo "${users[@]}"  # values
echo "${!users[@]}" # keys

for user in ${!users[@]}; do echo "user $user, ip ${users[$user]}"; done
```

Comment: Wouldn't
    grep "password for root from" /var/log/auth.log.1 | awk '{print $11}' |     grep -v repeated | sort | uniq be easier? If i use that, how would I patch in each of the ips into iptables statements?

Comment: There's nothing in the image. Better paste error here if any. Maybe you need to edit the awk command to set the right Nth columns instead of $6 and $8. For me it's $11 and $13

Comment: SO is not a free  coding service. Here, developers talk to other developers.